# Magento cannot create credit memo

Tags: magento

For certain orders  I can't seem to create a credit memo.
I think the only thing these products have in common is that they have a "Fixed product tax" for their disposal fee.

When I disabled 'FPT' in System>configuration>Tax>"fixed product tax" it did change the display of the product in the order but not the fixed price.

For example, the product per unit price is 1640 including regular taxes.

The additional fee is 5 (so the total amount is 1645) but when I disable the FPT the subtotal excludes the fee but in the total the fee is still added.

Since they all where test orders they all need to be credited, but I get the following message when I try "Can not save credit memo".

We are running Magento version 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

In the `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreditmemoController::saveAction` method is written that if you have the 'Cannot save the credit memo.' error message, you should check the exception log file. Check it and maybe you will solve the problem. Otherwise come back to us with the error message.

Comment: I can't seem to find what you mean. When the error occurs no files are changed/ added in magento-1.4/var ( report / log and so on ).

Comment: Turn on your logging: Admin > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes

Comment: dear vsushkov these settings are on.. on my main domain the last date the file was edited is today but on the subdomain it was november...

Comment: Dear vsushkov, i've edited writing permissions to the file exception.log. then i read "exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: Division by zero  in /var/www/vhosts/-censored-/subdomains/testomgeving/httpdocs/magento-1.4/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo/Total/Tax.php on line 85'" i've added if($orderShippingAmount != "0.000"){ and got it fixed! thanks a bunch!